# Content disappearing when trying to edit

Tags: content

When i click on a recently migrated blog to edit any of the posts, all of the content disappears. I read the previous post where some database info was given but I do not understand it. There was a plug in on the previous site which if this is the problem, was obviously not migrated to the free blog I am currently working on so how can I 'disable' or remove it if that site no longer exists?

What can I do please help?

Comment: How did you migrate your database. Did you make sure all your URL's are pointing to the new address and not the old one. There are a couple of posts done on migration on this site, know I have done one or two. Please use the site search and look at those topics. :-)

Answer (score -2):

Hello this often happen due to js:

for this i have solutions that.

please open your wp-config.php from root.

and add below code on it.

```
define(‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true);
```